# extract specific value from list

Tags: arrays, string, list, kotlin

I have a list of records that returns in the following format

```
Record(emailAddress=1234@gmail.com,Id=12313,optChoice=OUT, lastUpdateDate=2022-03-03T08:24:40.469898Z)

Record(emailAddress=56789@gmail.com,Id=12313,optChoice=in, lastUpdateDate=2022-04-03T08:24:40.469898Z)
```

I want to return my opt choice and everything else can be ignored. Any tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` function. For example: `list.map { it.optChoice }` (where `list` is the name of your list variable) which will return you a list of the optChoice values. See for more info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#map